# Why are memory addresses incremented by 54 on a x64 build config?

Tags: c++, memory, byte

In the Visual Studio memory debugging window I noticed something that threw me off a little.

The window is displaying addresses like so:

```
0x000001BB8F510DAC
0x000001BB8F510DE0
0x000001BB8F510E14
...
```

Meaning each newly specified address is incremented by 54.

On a x64 build I expected it to increment by +64 each time. Have I misunderstood something about computer memory here?

Kind regards

Comment: It's likely that the view that you are using to inspect the memory has 54 columns of bytes.

Comment: Does resizing memory window change anything?

Comment: FWIW I get 0x34 (52) as the difference between the addresses.

Comment: You haven't told us anything about the objects these pointers point to, so it's hard to say what would be expected.

Comment: @MarkRansom The *"Visual Studio memory debugging window"* is just a view on raw memory. It's a debugging tool. Those address don't necessarily correspond to objects.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I can't believe it, you're right. I have been sat here for an hour scratching my head over this. Embarrassing, but thanks.

Comment: its 64-bits not 64-bytes so each new address would be 8 bytes apart but as François said the 52 byte interval is just based on the width of the debug window and has no significance

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I have never used the memory debugging window, didn't even know it existed. I'll have to remember that.

Comment: @MarkRansom It's occasionally a very useful tool for debugging. Check it out!